# Nokia E63 phone CPU bottleneck

Tags: qt, mobile, cpu, nokia

I am creating an application for the [Nokia E63](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nokia_E63) using the Qt SDK. I can implement audio recording functionality by implementing a class that inherits [QIODevice](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qq/qq12-iodevice.html). Every time the phone hardware reads in new audio samples it forwards them to my `QIODevice` for writing.

My target recording frequency is 16000 Hz, but the device only supports 8000 Hz and 48000 Hz. I chose to record at 48000 and then re-sample it to 16000 Hz. This method records fine except after 10 seconds or so the phone crashes! I assume the reason for this is that the write function in my `QIODevice` can't keep up with the speed at which new samples are produced (48000 hz). The reason the write method can't keep up is because it has the additional overhead of re-sampling.

Would implementing the re-sampling and writing the samples to a file functions in a separate thread help?

In the write function of the recording `QIODevice`, I just copy the sample to a buffer and then have my re-sampling thread go around the buffer re-sampling and writing to file. Will this method work?

Comment: Did you take a look at [the spectrum demo](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/demos-spectrum.html) available in the Nokia Qt SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know much about Nokia development, but I assume that Nokia Qt SDK will have an phone Emulator of some sort. I'd say test it out first on the emulator to make sure its not a problem with your code. It could just be a bug within your code or maybe even a bug within Qt. Also try it out on a different phone to see if the issue is hardware related.